# If $r\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ is it possible that $r^{r^{r^r}}\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: reference-request, exponentiation, irrational-numbers, tetration

It's straightforward to prove that $r^r\notin\mathbb{Q}$, which furthermore allows us to use the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) to prove that $r^{r^r}\notin\mathbb{Q}$.

> Is it true that $r^{r^{r^r}}\notin\mathbb{Q}$?

It seems like it ought to be true, though my guess would be that this is an open problem. If not, does anyone know a proof? And if so, do there exist any discussions of it in the literature?

Comment: I would also guess that this is an open problem. It is even unknown whether the power-tower is an integer for $\ r=\pi\ $ (which would however be a miracle)

Comment: @darkmalthorp For the record, Gelfond-Schneider says that $r^{r^r}\notin\overline{\Bbb Q}$, not just $\notin\Bbb Q$ (though I presume you meant that).

Comment: Yes, indeed it is a stronger result :) Of course, I fully expect that $r^{r^{r^r}}$ is also transcendental.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp how do u prove $r^r \not \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proof_by_infinite_descent - the techniques for the proof by infinite descent here can be generalized in a straightforward way